# Android SimpleXml Parser Data Parser Error

Tags: android, kotlin

I got the following result from the API and I need to use this.

```
<resultcode>0</resultcode>
<config>
    <item>
        <c_no>1040120094364111</c_no>
        <cdate>20201224100000</cdate>
        <u_d>0</u_d>
        <fare>1250</fare>
        <balance>9750</balance>
        <area>AF0142</area>
        <bc_no>12</bc_no>
    </item>
    <item>
        <c_no>1040120094364111</c_no>
        <cdate>20201224100000</cdate>
        <u_d>0</u_d>
        <fare>1250</fare>
        <balance>9750</balance>
        <area>AF0142</area>
        <bc_no>12</bc_no>
    </item>
</config>
```

I am trying to parse the above data using SimpleXmlParser.

The data class I used is as follows

```
@Root
data class TransActionResponse @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field:ElementList(name = "config", required = false, inline = true)
    var config: TransActionConfig? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "resultCode", required = false)
    var resultCode: Int
)

@Root(name = "config", strict = false)
data class TransActionConfig @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field:ElementList(name = "item", required = false, inline = true)
    var item: ArrayList<TransActionItem> = arrayListOf()
)
```

However, the following error occurs

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,67]
    Message: start tag not allowed in epilog but got c
```

How can I parse the above data? Please help me

Comment: use https://github.com/Tickaroo/tikxml SimpleXmlConverterFactory is deprecated

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you solve the above problem with tikxml?

Comment: sure i wil post the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/Tickaroo/tikxml as https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/simplexml is deprecated

Add the below to build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.github.Tickaroo.tikxml:annotation:0.8.15'
implementation 'com.github.Tickaroo.tikxml:core:0.8.15'
kapt 'com.github.Tickaroo.tikxml:processor-common:0.8.15'
kapt 'com.github.Tickaroo.tikxml:processor:0.8.15'
```

In case you are using retrofit

```
implementation 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:retrofit-converter:0.8.15'
```

Don't forget to add

```
plugins {'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

While building retrofit add the below

```
 .addConverterFactory(
        TikXmlConverterFactory.create(
            TikXml.Builder()
                .exceptionOnUnreadXml(false)
                .build()
        )
 )
```

Your data class

```
@Xml
data class TransactionResponse (
@PropertyElement(name = "resultcode")
var resultcode: Int = 0,

@Element(name="config")
var config: Config
```

)

Your config class

```
@Xml
data class Config( @Element
                   var item: List<Item>)
```

Your item class

```
@Xml
data class Item (
    @PropertyElement(name="c_no")
    var cNumber: String,

    @PropertyElement(name="c_date")
    var date: String,

    @PropertyElement(name="u_d)
    var uD: Int = 0,

    @PropertyElement(name="fare")
    var fare: Int = 0,

    @PropertyElement(name="balance")
    var balance: Int = 0,

    @PropertyElement(name="area")
    var area: String,

    @PropertyElement(name="bc_no")
    var bcno: Int = 0
)
```

If you log you should see

```
Result code: 0
Area code: AF0142
C Number: 1040120094364111
Area code: AF0142
C Number: 1040120094364111
```